# Evaluate a list of computation expression values

Tags: f#

What's a good way to evaluate a list of computation expression values into the corresponding list of values?

Let's say my computation expression type is `M<a>`  then I'm wondering what is the best way to write the function:

```
mysequence : list<M<'a>> -> M<list<'a>>
```

I could write this out recursively:

```
let rec mysequence = function
    | [] -> builder { return [] }
    | (x::xs) -> builder { let! y = x
                           let! ys = mysequence xs
                           return (y::ys)
                         }
```

Is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make this a bit shorter by using `List.fold` and even shorter if you introduced a couple of helper combinators such as a `lift2` function of the following type:

```
lift2 : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> M<'a> -> M<'b> -> M<'c>
```

This is something you can easily define using the `builder { .. }` notation and it lets you turn functions that work on normal values into functions that work on wrapped values. You could then lift the list consing operation and use that with fold. Doing that will make the code shorter (if you ignore all the helpers one has to write), but it also makes it pretty ugly and obscure.

If I was writing this, I'd go with something very close to your version. I prefer to keep the entire body in `builder { .. }` rather than having `function` and I'd also use the accumulator parameter, so I'd write:

```
let rec mysequence acc input = builder {
  match input with 
  | [] -> return List.rev acc
  | x::xs -> 
      let! y = x
      return! mysequence (y::acc) xs }
```

But aside from the accumulator and some minor syntactic differences, it's pretty much the same as yours!